# Pandas dataframe grouped aggregation on multiple columns with user defined function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I'm trying to use grouped aggregation on multiple columns with a user-defined function on a data frame.
The data frame would look like this. I want to do some aggregation on [volume] and [logRet] group by [monthEndDate] and [stock]

The data frame would look like this

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| date          monthEndDate  stock  volume  logRet |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1990-01-01    1990-01-31    A      1       NA     |
| 1990-01-02    1990-01-31    A      2       0.2    |
| 1990-02-01    1990-02-28    A      3       0.3    |
| 1990-02-02    1990-02-28    A      4       0.4    |
| ...           ...                                 |
| 1990-01-01    1990-01-31    B      1       NA     |
| 1990-01-02    1990-01-31    B      2       0.08   |
| ...           ...                                 |
| 1990-02-01    1990-02-28    B      0       0.3    |
| 1990-02-02    1990-02-28    B      3       0.4    |
| ...           ...                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I tried the following method:

```py
def check_input(fn):
    def wrapper(_s, *args, **kwargs):
        if not isinstance(_s, (pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, np.array)):
            raise TypeError()
        return fn(_s, *args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
    return wrapper


@check_input
def varLogRet(_s):
    return pd.Series({'varLogRet': np.var(_s[np.nonzero(_s)])})


@check_input
def TotRet1M(_s):
    return pd.Series({'TotRet1M': np.exp(np.sum(_s))})


@check_input
def avgVolume(_s):
    return pd.Series({'avgVolume': np.mean(_s[np.nonzero(_s)])})

return_m = price_d.groupby(['monthEndDate', 'tradingItemId']).agg({'logRet': [varLogRet, TotRet1M],
                                                                       'volume': avgVolume})
```

However, it failed with a ValueError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 663, in agg_series
    return self._aggregate_series_fast(obj, func)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 681, in _aggregate_series_fast
    result, counts = grouper.get_result()
  File "pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx", line 429, in pandas._libs.reduction.SeriesGrouper.get_result
  File "pandas/_libs/reduction.pyx", line 413, in pandas._libs.reduction.SeriesGrouper.get_result
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 894, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-15-37583dd006b9>", line 5, in wrapper
    return fn(_s, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-15-37583dd006b9>", line 22, in avgVolume
    return pd.Series({'avgVolume': np.mean(_s[np.nonzero(_s)])})
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1113, in __getitem__
    return self._get_with(key)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1127, in _get_with
    return self._get_values_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1172, in _get_values_tuple
    raise ValueError("Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex")
ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-19-278a006fcb71>", line 1, in <module>
    return_m = price_d.groupby(['monthEndDate', 'tradingItemId']).agg({'volume': avgVolume})
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 1455, in aggregate
    return super().aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 229, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(func, _level=_level, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 506, in _aggregate
    result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 456, in _agg
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 440, in _agg_1dim
    return colg.aggregate(how, _level=(_level or 0) + 1)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 860, in aggregate
    return self._python_agg_general(func_or_funcs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 900, in _python_agg_general
    result, counts = self.grouper.agg_series(obj, f)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 665, in agg_series
    return self._aggregate_series_pure_python(obj, func)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 694, in _aggregate_series_pure_python
    res = func(group)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 894, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-15-37583dd006b9>", line 5, in wrapper
    return fn(_s, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-15-37583dd006b9>", line 22, in avgVolume
    return pd.Series({'avgVolume': np.mean(_s[np.nonzero(_s)])})
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1113, in __getitem__
    return self._get_with(key)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1127, in _get_with
    return self._get_values_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\venvs\factor_model\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1172, in _get_values_tuple
    raise ValueError("Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex")
ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `.iloc` fixed the issue for me. The reason is because `nonzero()` function returns the index of the array in which you need to use `iloc` for selection.

```py
def varLogRet(_s):
    return pd.Series({'varLogRet': np.var(_s.iloc[_s.to_numpy().nonzero()])})

def TotRet1M(_s):
    return pd.Series({'TotRet1M': np.exp(np.sum(_s))})

def avgVolume(_s):
    return pd.Series({'avgVolume': np.mean(_s.iloc[_s.to_numpy().nonzero()])})

temp.\
    groupby(['monthEndDate', 'stock']).\
    agg({'logRet': [varLogRet, TotRet1M], 'volume': avgVolume})
```

Output

```
                            logRet  volume
                varLogRet   TotRet1M    avgVolume
monthEndDate    stock           
1990-01-31  A   0.0000      1.221403    1.5
1990-02-28  B   0.0025      2.013753    3.5
...
```

Also, I use `_s.to_numpy().nonzero()` instead of `np.nonzero(_s)` just because I am using a different version to you. It is recommended to use my version from `pandas 0.24.0` - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.nonzero.html#pandas-series-nonzero.